# single-row subquery returns more than one row oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables like below:

**Test**

```
    +--------------+--------+
    | Test_Case_ID | Status |
    +--------------+--------+
    |           10 | PASS   |
    |           20 | FAIL   |
    |           30 | FAIL   |
    +--------------+--------+
```

**Defect**

```
    +-----------+
    | Defect_ID |
    +-----------+
    |       500 |
    |       400 |
    +-----------+
```

and **link1**

```
    +--------------+-----------+
    | Test_Case_ID | Defect_ID |
    +--------------+-----------+
    |           20 |       500 |
    |           30 |       500 |
    |           30 |       400 |
    +--------------+-----------+
```

I am trying the below query

```
select 
test.test_case_id,
test.status,
case when test.status = 'FAIL' then 
(select link1.defect_id 
from link1 
where 
test.test_case_id = link1.test_case_id) 
end as defect1_id
from test test
```

I get the below error "Error    12/20/2012 10:05:17 AM  0:00:00.093 Toad for Data Analysts: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row    1   78
"

Is there a way to retrieve both the records for "30" from the link table? Because i want to display that test case 30 is failing because of defect 500 & 400.

Thanks so much

Comment: your where clause is reversed in the sub query

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel You mean it should be `where link1.test_case_id = test.test_case_id`. I tried that as well and still get the same error.

Comment: You have two records in link with Test_Case_ID = 30.  Which Defect_ID do you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using a `JOIN` instead of the subquery:

```
select 
  t.test_case_id,
  t.status,
  case when t.status = 'FAIL' then l.defect_id  
    end as defect1_id
from test t
left join link1 l
  on t.test_case_id = l.test_case_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c339/2)

This will return both records, then you can decide which item to return in your final result.

Result:

```
| TEST_CASE_ID | STATUS | DEFECT1_ID |
--------------------------------------
|           20 |   FAIL |        500 |
|           30 |   FAIL |        500 |
|           30 |   FAIL |        400 |
|           10 |   PASS |     (null) |
```

Based on your comment, if you are using Oracle 11g, then you can use the `LISTAGG()` function to combine the records into one row:

```
select 
  t.test_case_id,
  t.status,
  case 
    when t.status = 'FAIL' 
    then listagg(l.defect_id, ', ')
          within group (order by l.defect_id)
  end as defect1_id
from test t
left join link1 l
  on t.test_case_id = l.test_case_id
group by t.test_case_id, t.status
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c339/3)

Result:

```
| TEST_CASE_ID | STATUS | DEFECT1_ID |
--------------------------------------
|           10 |   PASS |     (null) |
|           20 |   FAIL |        500 |
|           30 |   FAIL |   400, 500 |
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve both the records for "30" from the link table? Because i want to display that test case 30 is failing because of defect 500 & 400.

Comment: this query does retrieve both records did you see the demo?

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet for your time in looking into this. Just curious to know can't we display both the defect_ids in one record in output rather than two rows..I think it sound stupid..just want to know..Thanks

Comment: @javanoob Yes you can, what version of oracle?

Comment: @javanoob see my edit, you can use `LISTAGG` to consolidate the rows

Answer (score 4):

You have two rows in the link table that have values of "30".  This is your problem.

Which of these rows do you want?

To fix the subquery, you can either say `select max(link1.defect_id)` or add `and rownum = 1` to the `where` clause.

What you want is probably a bi more complicated.  How about this version, which concatenates the defects into a string:

```
select t.test_case_id, t.status,
       listagg(cast(l.defect_id as varchar(32)) within group (order by l.defect_id) as defects
from test t left join
     link1 l
     on t.test_case_id = l.test_case_id
group by t.test_case_id, t.status
```

You don't specify the version of Oracle.  If `listagg` is not available, then `wm_concat` probably is.  [Here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) is a reference on different ways to concat strings in an aggregation in Oracle.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve both the records for "30" from the link table? Because i want to display that test case 30 is failing because of defect 500 & 400.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your time in looking into my question.